# get the current tab title with a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to get the tab title that I am currently opening, the code has two parts, the first one is working correctly and the second is not.
the second code return undefined when I try to open a link from a tab, in that case, a new tab shows up but I get undefined

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => { console.log('Extension is running!'); });
var y
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function (tab) {
        y = tab.title
        console.log("you are here: Background" + tab.title);
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
    if (tab.active && change.url) {
        console.log("you are here: url " + change.title);
    }
});
```

Comment: `change.url` is only present when the URL has actually changed. Could that be the problem?

Comment: the URL usually changes when we open a new link, the problem happens when I open a page from the tab that i am currently browsing, but when i change the tab i can see the title without a problem, so i am trying to see the title when the URL changes but i am still on the same tab

Comment: So are you opening the link in a new tab or not?

Comment: no still the same tab